# Spring batch job start processing file not fully uploaded to the SFTP server

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

I have a spring-batch job scanning the SFTP server at a given interval. When it finds a new file, it starts the processing.

It works fine for most cases, but there is one case when it doesn't work:

1. User starts uploading a new file to the SFTP server
2. Batch job checks the server and finds a new file
3. It start processing it

But since the file is still being uploaded, during the processing it encounters unexpected end of input block, and the error occurs.

How can I check that file was fully uploaded to the SFTP server before batch job processing starts?

Answer (score 2):

Locking files while uploading / Upload to temporary file name

You may have an automated system monitoring a remote folder and you want to prevent it from accidentally picking a file that has not finished uploading yet. As majority of SFTP and FTP servers (WebDAV being an exception) do not support file locking, you need to prevent the automated system from picking the file otherwise.

Common workarounds are:

1. Upload “done” file once an upload of data files finishes and have
   the automated system wait for the “done” file before processing the
   data files. This is easy solution, but won’t work in multi-user
   environment.
2. Upload data files to temporary (“upload”) folder and move them atomically to target folder once the upload finishes.
3. Upload data files to distinct temporary name, e.g. with .filepart extension, and rename them atomically once the upload finishes. Have the automated system ignore the .filepart files.

Got from [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_locking_files_while_uploading)

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem, Our solution was, we configured spring-batch cron trigger to trigger the job every 10min(though we could configure for 5min, as file transfer was taking less than 3min), then we read/process all the files created prior to 10 minutes.  We assume the FTP operation completes within 3 minutes.  This gave us some additional flexibility such as when spring-batch app was down etc.

For example if the batch job triggered at 10:20AM we read all the files that were created before 10:10AM, like-wise job that runs at 10:30, reads all the files created before 10:20.

**Note:** Once Read you need to either delete or move to history folder for duplicate reads.